# Select with search option in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is kind of a long shot, but is there anyway I can incorporate a search button in Bootstrap's select inputs? I have loads of options, and would like to give my user the flexibility and comfort of going through the entire list with a search feature.

I found a couple of good tools, but would like to know the best based on people with more experience than I do.

To further understand what I mean, I would like to have a select input like this:
[image]

You can see in the picture, if the user types in A, the countries with A show up.

Is there any plugin that allows this feature? I also would like it if I could have a selected option too (similar to the selected attribute in html). So for example if I want to have 'Argentina' already selected directly through html, it should, but the user could change it.

Comment: you can use [select2](https://select2.github.io/)

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik The question is tagged with bootstrap and it seems that select2 is another thing.

Comment: @Tim1234 select2 is plugin, compatible with bootstrap just like link you've provided [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you tag the question with `bootstrap`, I assume you do not accept other approaches like jquery. If you have imported bootstrap, the following code should be something you want:

```
<select class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
<option>Apples</option>
<option>Boys</option>
<option>Cats</option>
</select>
```

This [link](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/#live-search) provided more details.

Comment: The example doesn't work without bootstrap-select plugin, and the link is broken, here is the one that works: https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/